# How can I exclude code path when bundling with webpack/browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, webpack

I have a library that can be used with both node.js and the browser. I am using CommonJS then publishing for the web version using webpack. My code looks like this:

```
// For browsers use XHR adapter
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // This adapter uses browser's XMLHttpRequest
  require('./adapters/xhr');
}
// For node use HTTP adapter
else if (typeof process !== 'undefined') {
  // This adapter uses node's `http`
  require('./adapters/http');
}
```

The problem I am encountering is that when I run webpack (browserify would do the same) the generated output includes `http` along with all it's dependencies. This results in a HUGE file which is not optimal for browser performance.

My question is how can I exclude the node code path when running a module bundler? I solved this temporarily by using webpack's externals and just returning undefined when including `'./adapters/http'`. This doesn't solve the use case where other developers depend on my library using CommonJS. Their build will end up with the same problem unless they use similar exclude config.

I've looked at using envify, just wondering if there is another/better solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

You may use `IgnorePlugin` for Webpack. If you are using a webpack.config.js file, use it like this:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

var ignore = new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^(canvas|mongoose|react)$/)

module.exports = {
  //other options goes here
  plugins: [ignore]
}
```

To push it further, you may use some flags like `process.env.NODE_ENV` to control the regex filter of IgnorePlugin

Answer (score 5):

In order to exclude `node_modules` and native node libraries from being bundled, you need to:

1. Add `target: 'node'` to your `webpack.config.js`. This will [exclude native node modules](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target) (path, fs, etc.) from being bundled.
2. Use [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) in order to exclude all other `node_modules`.

So your result config file should look like:

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
...
module.exports = {
    ...
    target: 'node', // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc. 
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder 
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked best for me

```
var _process;

try {
    _process = eval("process");  // avoid browserify shim
} catch (e) {}

var isNode = typeof _process==="object" && _process.toString()==="[object process]";
```

as Node will return `true` and not only will the browser return `false`, but [browserify](https://npmjs.com/package/browserify) will not include its `process` shim when compiling your code. As a result, your browserified code will be smaller.

**Edit**: I wrote a package to handle this more cleanly: [broquire](https://npmjs.com/broquire)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `require.ensure` for bundle splitting. For example

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    console.log("Loading browser XMLHttpRequest");

    require.ensure([], function(require){

        // require.ensure creates a bundle split-point
        require('./adapters/xhr');
    });
} else if (typeof process !== 'undefined') {
    console.log("Loading node http");

    require.ensure([], function(require){

        // require.ensure creates a bundle split-point
        require('./adapters/http');
    });
}
```

See [code splitting](http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) for more information and a sample demo usage [here](http://cuttleblog.tumblr.com/post/63669845272/webpack#bundle-splitting)