# Exclude module from webpack minification

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundling-and-minification

We are using WebPack in a single page application. The application is deployed to many environments. We have a requirement where the application needs to call a specific endpoint in a given environment.

In order to provide the endpoint address for the given environment is to have an environments module. This is the current solution (there are many and this is not the point of the question). However we need to exclude the config.js from minification so that it can be overwritten as part of the deployment process.

The config.js looks like the following:

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        endpointUrl: 'http://1.2.3.4',
        authUrl: 'http://5.6.7.8'
    }
};
```

And is referenced using the following:

```
const endpointUrl = config.env.endpointUrl;
const authUrl = config.env.authUrl;
```

The WebPack config looks like the following:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
​
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './src/js/main.jsx',
        login: './src/js/login-main.jsx'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            plugins: ['transform-react-jsx'],
            query: {stage: 0}
        }, {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'eslint-loader'
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            fetch: 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __DEV__: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.env.DEV || false))
        })
    ]
};
```

So far we have looked at [externals](http://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html) and [module loaders](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html) but have not found anything that works. The exclude in the module loader still causes the module to be minified.

Some SO questions that we have looked at:

- [Exclude react from webpack bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154285/exclude-react-from-webpack-bundle)
- [Webpack and external libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530254/webpack-and-external-libraries)
- [How can I exclude code path when bundling with webpack/browserify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834396/how-can-i-exclude-code-path-when-bundling-with-webpack-browserify)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Webpack [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) are a good option to avoid bundle certain dependencies.

> However we need to exclude the config.js from minification so that it
>   can be overwritten as part of the deployment process.

Adding a dependency as external not only excludes it from minification but it is not even resolved by webpack.

### webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  externals: {
    './config': 'config'
  }
};
```

Add as external the path used to require your `config.js`. In my simple example the path corresponds to `./config`. Associate it to the global variable that will contain your configuration object. In my case I just used `config` as the variable name (see below `config.js`).

### index.js

```
const config = require('./config');

const endpointUrl = config.env.endpointUrl;
const authUrl = config.env.authUrl;

console.log(endpointUrl);
console.log(authUrl);
```

As you are preventing webpack to resolve the `config.js` module then it has to be available in the environment during runtime. One way could be to expose it as a `config` variable in the global context.

### config.js

```
window.config = {
  env: {
    endpointUrl: 'http://1.2.3.4',
    authUrl: 'http://5.6.7.8'
  }
};
```

Then you can load a specific `config.js` file for any given environment.

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Webpack</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This did exactly what we wanted although it is worth pointing out that you need to add the copying of the config.js to the build folder to your web pack script.

Answer (score 5):

I think [uglify-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-loader) might do the trick. It provides you more control over the minification result than what you get out of the box.