# Webpack TerserPlugin - exclude node module

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

Using a custom Angular Builder, I'm trying to exclude an entire module from minification/optimization.

The Webpack `.md` file says

> **exclude**
>   Type: String|RegExp|Array Default: undefined
>
> Files to exclude.

Can I use this setting to exclude an entire directory (which is the node module)?

---

The current code is

```
export default class CustomizeTerserBrowserBuilder extends BrowserBuilder {
  public buildWebpackConfig(root: any, projectRoot: any, host: any, options: any): any {
    const webpackConfig = super.buildWebpackConfig(root, projectRoot, host, options);

    if (
      webpackConfig.optimization &&
      webpackConfig.optimization.minimizer &&
      Array.isArray(webpackConfig.optimization.minimizer)
    ) {
      const terserPlugin = (webpackConfig.optimization.minimizer as any[]).find(
        minimizer => minimizer instanceof TerserPlugin
      );

      if (terserPlugin) {
        terserPlugin.options.exclude = [/node_modules/];
      }
    }

    return webpackConfig;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this

```
   module.exports = {
      optimization: {
        minimizer: [
          new TerserPlugin({
            exclude: /node_modules/,
          }),
        ],
      },
    };
```

Comment: So this is a Regex that will match the entire `node_modules` folder?

Comment: @LppEdd I have similar config [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js#L105)

Comment: Tried but it still minifies and removes the wrong functions. I think it is because I'm using an Angular Builder to modify the default TerserPlugin configuration.

Comment: Infact files still have the build-optimizer extensions (e.g. `Viewer.js.pre-build-optimizer.js`)

Comment: Try this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915826/exclude-module-from-webpack-minification) I think it might help you

Comment: The problem is I'm not using Webpack directly. I'm passing by Angular CLI (Devkit Builder)

Comment: Okay, I think I'll have to `ng eject`. Thus I'll have the standard `webpack.config.json` file.

Comment: If I use `/.js/` it works fine. That means the `node_modules` isn't included in the file name?

Comment: Where is .js thing you said ?

Comment: What I need to ignore are `node_modules/bpmn-js/lib/Viewer.js` and `node_modules/bpmn-js/lib/Modeler.js`

Comment: In the end there is no solution to this problem for Angular. Thanks anyway

Comment: I was able to override the `sideEffects` key, using `module.rules.sideEffects`. So now the Angular build optimizer will simply skip that module.

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same issue on production with Webpack5, ended up going with something like following which will exclude specific files under `node_modules` or `dist` which cause Terser's "aggressive" minification attempts to break.

```js
optimization: {
    minimize: NODE_ENV !== 'development', //only minimize on production
    //JS minimizer when "minimize === true",
    minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(?:node_modules|dist)\/(update-notifier|numeral|jackspeak|bulma-extensions)\//, //whatever causes u a problem, either as RegExp or as a string[]
            terserOptions: {
                parse: {
                    bare_returns: true //allow code with returns outside of functions, solved a ton of issues.
                },
            },
        })],
    // rest of config.
    // ...

}
```

To be honest I'm not sure if excluding ALL files under `/node_modules` is a good idea.